# Is there a way to make ExpressJS log runtime errors?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I recently ran into an issue where an express route of mine was hanging, and it took me forever to finally figure out that I had a typo in one of my function calls, so it was trying to call a function that did not exist.

For example:

```
router.get('/example', function(req, res) {
    UserService.nonExistentFunction();
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

To me this feels like it should have been something that stuck out like a sore thumb, in the form of a runtime exception in my log. However, the server did nothing, the request just hung silently with no hints as to what went wrong.

Is there a better way to catch these dummy-type errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own error handler in Express.http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html
Depends on your perferences, you can log the error in the console or to a file. In my application, I am doing something like this,

```
import debug = require('debug');
var app = module.exports = express();
var errorLogger = debug('error');

// Error handling
app.use(logErrors);
app.use(clientErrorHandler);
app.use(errorHandler);

// Handle 404
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send('Sorry cant find that!');
});


function logErrors(err, req, res, next) {
  errorLogger(err.stack);
  next(err);
}

function clientErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if (req.xhr) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!', status: 500 });
  } else {
    next(err);
  }
}

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500);
  res.render('error', { error: err, status: 500 });
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had almost this exact code in from the docs, but it wasn't working because it wasn't the very last thing in call chain, so the error hadn't happened yet, thus why the request was hanging. Now it's working as expected thank you!